# Why does `git clone` override global core.symlinks on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, symlink

I found that `git clone` sets local `core.symlinks` value as `false` by default even when I have set `core.symlinks` as `true`.

```
> git config --list --show-origin
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=input
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.diff=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.status=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.branch=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.interactive=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       help.format=html
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       rebase.autosquash=true
-- snip --

> cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/saschanaz/eslint-plugin-import
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because I didn't enable [Developer Mode](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/#rqi7fmSQ8BriHL9f.97) and thus git couldn't create symlinks without admin privilege. Enabling it allows future clones to get proper symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

`core.symlinks` is, regrettably, overloaded in Git for Windows.

If you have `core.symlinks` set to `true` when you create a repository (whether by running `git init` or `git clone`), then git will actually attempt to detect if symlinks are supported in the working directory you're creating, and if so, it will *then* set the repository's `core.symlinks` to true.

If they are *not* supported (because, for example, you didn't enable Developer Mode) then the repository's `core.symlinks` configuration option will be set to `false`.

So the first option serves as a mechanism that you can specify if you want symbolic links.  The second acts like a cache of whether symlinks are supported on the platform so that it doesn't need to detect this during every operation (much like `core.ignorecase`).

Comment: Thanks, but what are the first and second options mentioned are here?